# How to integrate Javascript into C# and run scriptcode step by step

Tags: c#, javascript, mmo

We are currently working on a Pokemon MMO trying to figure out how to implement an asynchronous scripting language the best. We don't want to work with threads or tasks, but the goal was to wait for specific commands like the `messageBox("Hello World")`-Command and stuff like that.

Is there any general solution for our problem?

Comment: You can easily integrate Javascript into your game using stuff like JINT. See here for an example http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2012/06/05/using-javascript-as-a-script-engine-in-xnac/ (disclaimer: that is my blog!)